# JasperReport PDF export empty, RTF export fine

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

When exporting a JasperReport created with ireport designer 5.0.1 using the Java API the report is always empty. In the report I have set whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail. Also using new JREmptyDataSource() also does not work.

Also when I export as RTF using JRRtfExporter the result is just fine. Also the PDF preview in ireport correct.

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test-report.jasper");
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, new HashMap<String, Object>(), new JRXmlDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream("<root><name>John Doe</name</root>".getBytes("UTF-8")), "/root"));

JRPdfExporter reportExporter = new JRPdfExporter();//JRRtfExporter(); does works fine
reportExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jPrint);
reportExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
reportExporter.exportReport();
out.close();
reportBytes = out.toByteArray();
```

reportBytes is saved to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The code is perfectly fine. The problem was that I saved the exposed the response as a binary webservice attachment. Next I copied this output to a PDF file. However in doing so some of the binary characters where lost.

Unfortunately, Adobe Reader does not complain about an incorrect PDF format, it just displays a blank PDF.